Electrostatic potential outside of a charged ball
To preface, I have never solved Maxwell's equation or his resulting Poisson's equation in any coordinate scheme, nor am I a physics major. I'm entirely teaching myself how to do this, so I don't know all of the typical conventions surrounding this problem. A didactic explanation would be appreciated.
We want the electrostatic potential produced outside of a uniformly charged ball or radius $r = 1$.
$$\nabla^2V(\textbf{r}) = -\frac{\rho(\textbf{r})}{\epsilon}\\ \cases{V(r,0,\phi) = V(r,2\pi,\phi) \\ V'(r,0,\phi) = V'(r,2\pi,\phi) \\ V(R,\theta,\phi) = V(\theta,\phi)} \\ \rho(\textbf{r}) = \cases{2 & $0<r\le 1\land0<\theta<\pi\land0<\phi<2\pi$ \\ 0 & otherwise}$$
The distance (or this is technically $||\vec{A}||$ which is the norm) in spherical coordinates between the potential at position vector $\textbf{r}$ and point charge $\textbf{r}_0$ is $||\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|| = \sqrt{r^2 + r_0^2 - 2rr_0[\sin\theta\sin\theta_0\cos(\phi-\phi_0)+\cos\theta\cos\theta_0]}$
If we have complete spherical symmetry such that $\theta = \theta_0,\phi = \phi_0$, then $||\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|| = \sqrt{r^2 + r_0^2 - 2rr_0}$, right? Not a rhetorical question, I'm actually asking.
From Laplace's Equation, we can build Green's function for Poisson's Equation in spherical coordinates as $G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0) = -\frac{1}{4\pi|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|}$, where $\textbf{r}$. Our solution in the general form $u(\textbf{r}) = \int f(\textbf{r}_0)G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0)d\textbf{r}^3_0$ is:
$$V(\textbf{r}) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\int_{\textbf{V}_0} \frac{\rho(\textbf{r}_0)}{||\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0||}d\textbf{r}_0^3$$
Method 1
I've asked this problem in a couple other places, and quite heavily I've seen reference to Gauss's Law which I'll write out below:
Gauss's Law from Divergence Theorem (where we understand that the volume integral of density is density * volume):
$$\int_V\Big(\nabla \cdot \nabla V(\textbf{r}) = \nabla \cdot \textbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\Big)dV = \frac{q}{\epsilon_0}\\
=\oint_S \textbf{E} \cdot d\textbf{S} = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi \textbf{E} \cdot \hat{\textbf{n}}r^2\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi = \frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$$
Something about creating a Gaussian surface at $R \ge 1$ for an open ended solution and which is perpendicular to the electric field so that the unit normal vector (which is also parallel to $\hat{\textbf{r}}$) yields:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\pi |E| R^2\sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi = \frac{q}{\epsilon_0}$$
$|E|$ is exactly the same over the entire surface because our charge density uniform throughout, so this evaluates to $4\pi R^2|E| = q$ where $q$ inside the Gaussian sphere at any point $R$ is the same because the charges only exist within the ball. If the Gaussian surface were inside the ball, I would have to find q within that surface and we'd be multiplying the uniform charge density by $R^3$ instead.
$$|E| = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon R^2} = \frac{2r^3}{3\epsilon R^2}$$ for r = 1.
And the electric field always points normally outward from the surface (if it's uniformly charged) so $$\textbf{E} = |E|\hat{\textbf{E}} = |E|\hat{\textbf{r}} = \frac{2}{3\pi\epsilon R^2}\hat{\textbf{r}}$$
$$V = \nabla \cdot \textbf{E} = \frac{1}{R^2}\frac{\partial R^2 \frac{2r^3}{3\epsilon R^2}}{\partial R}+0+0 = 0$$
So that didn't work out.
Method 2
If I instead mashed all the charges together into a single charge at the center $r=0$ and make the electric field experienced at $R \ge 1 \land 0 \le \theta \le \pi \land 0 \le \phi \le 1$, I think I'd get
$$q(\textbf{r}) = 2\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0) = 2\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 \frac{\delta(r-R)\delta(\theta-\theta_0)\delta(\phi-\phi_0)}{r^2 \sin\theta}$$
I'd just need to figure out what my $\delta$s would be and plug it into
$$V(r,\theta,\phi) = +\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{q(r_0,\theta_0,\phi_0)}{\sqrt{r^2 + r_0^2 - 2rr_0[\sin\theta\sin\theta_0\cos(\phi-\phi_0)+\cos\theta\cos\theta_0]}}r_0^2\sin\theta_0dr_0d\theta_0 d\phi_0$$,
and we can eliminate terms as we determine lack of dependencies. My assumption (and PLEASE correct me if this is wrong) is that there is no dependency on $\phi$ or $\theta$. We have a delta representing where our small bundle of charges are at the origin so can represent our bundle of charges as $\frac{4}{3}\pi (1)^3 \delta(r)$ meaning that at $r=0$ (which again is at the origin), there is a bundle of $\frac{4}{3}\pi (1)^3$ charges. Our integral becomes:
$$V(r,\theta,\phi) = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3 (1)^2\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2\delta\big(r_0)}{\sqrt{r^2 + r_0^2 - 2rr_0}}dr_0 = \frac{2}{3\epsilon|r|}$$
PLEASE let me know if this integral looks correct!
And we want V outside of the sphere and we've defined earlier that $R>=1$, so we could probably get away with a simple substitution: $V(r=R) = \frac{2}{3\epsilon|R|}$

The result should be $$V(R) = |\frac{q_{ball}}{4\pi\epsilon R}| = \frac{2}{3\epsilon |R|}$$
If anyone can point out where I messed up in method 1, or any potential mistakes in my reasoning in method 2 (or the setup of the integral!), that would be great!

EDIT:
To correct some things I said earlier in the comments, 1)the bounds of integration from -1 to 1 that I was previously confused about comes from u-substitution changing the bounds of integration, and 2) I made a mistake in my comment about applying Green's formula, because $\alpha = 0$ when using infinite space Green's Function due to the solution $V(\theta,\phi)$ on the boundary at $r\rightarrow \infty$ = 0. So the boundary integral $\oint_{\partial \Omega}$ would yield 0 due to the solution being 0 on that boundary.
So, we can't really apply the boundary condition of $V(\theta,\phi)$ on the surface using Green's function in this way, and I think we would instead have to use: $$G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0) = -\frac{1}{4\pi|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|} + V_h(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0)$$ where $V_h(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0)$ is the homogeneous solution satisfying homogeneous boundary conditions i.e. $\nabla^2 V_h(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0) = 0$

Starting from the general form of the electrostatic equations $$\begin{align}\mathbf{\nabla} \times\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})&=0 \tag{1} \label{1}, \\[5pt] \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})&= \rho(\mathbf{r})/\epsilon_0, \tag{2} \label{2}\end{align}$$ eq. \eqref{1} implies that the electric field can be written as the gradient of a scalar potential $V(\mathbf{r})$,  $$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=- \mathbf{\nabla} V(\mathbf{r}). \tag{3} \label{3}$$ Inserting eq. \eqref{3} into eq.\eqref{2}, one obtains the Poisson equation $$\Delta V(\mathbf{r})=-\rho(\mathbf{r})/\epsilon_0. \tag{4} \label{4}$$ Emplyoing the fact that $$\Delta (1/|\mathbf{r}|)=-4 \pi \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{r}) \tag{5}$$ and the translation invariance of the Laplace operator $\Delta$, the general solution of eq. \eqref{4} is given by $$V(\mathbf{r}) = -\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} \! d^3{\mathbf{r}}^\prime \, \frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}^\prime)}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime|}+ V_{\rm h}(\mathbf{r}), \tag{6} \label{6}$$ where $V_{\rm h}(\mathbf{r})$ is the general solution of the homogeneous equation $\Delta V_{\rm h}(\mathbf{r})=0$. Note that  $V_h$ is determined by the boundary conditions of the electrostatic problem. The general solution for the electric field is obtained by inserting  eq. \eqref{6} into eq. \eqref{3}: $$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})= \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} \! d^3 {\mathbf{r}^\prime} \, \frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}^\prime)}{(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime)^2} \frac{\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime|}+ \mathbf{E}_{\rm h}(\mathbf{r}). \tag{7}    $$
Using the integral theorem of Gauss, eq. \eqref{2} can be written in the mathematically equivalent form $$ \int\limits_{\partial G} \! d \mathbf{f} \cdot \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) = \int\limits_G \! d^3 \mathbf{r} \, \rho(\mathbf{r})/\epsilon_0, \tag{8} \label{8}$$ where $G \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is an arbitrary domain with boundary $\partial G$.
For your special case with charge distribution $$\rho(\mathbf{r})= \rho_0 \Theta(R-|\mathbf{r}|), \tag{9} \label{9}$$ one can take advantage of the radial symmetry of the problem, implying the existence of a solution of the form $$\mathbf{E} (\mathbf{r}) =E(r) \, \mathbf{r}/r, \qquad r= |\mathbf{r}|. \tag{10} \label{10}$$ Using eq. \eqref{8} with $G= B_r(0)$ one finds $$E(r)=\frac{\rho_0}{3 \epsilon_0}\left[r \, \Theta(R-r)+ \frac{R^3}{r^2} \Theta(r-R)    \right]. \tag{11} \label{11}$$ It is easy to check that the solution \eqref{11} fulfills indeed eq. \eqref{2} $$\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) = (1/r^2) \partial(r^2 E(r))= \rho_0 \Theta(R-r) /\epsilon_0. \tag{12}$$
The associated potential is now immediately obtained by $$\begin{align}   V(r)&= -\int\limits_\infty^r \! dr^\prime E(r^\prime) \\[5pt] &= \frac{\rho_0}{3 \epsilon_0} \left[\frac{R^3}{r} \Theta(r-R)+ \frac{3R^2-r^2}{2}  \Theta(R-r)   \right].\end{align} \tag{13} \label{13}$$ Using the formula $ \Delta f(r)/r = -4 \pi f(0) \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{r}) +f^{\prime \prime}(r)/r$, it is again easy to check $\Delta V(r) = -\rho_0 \Theta(R-r) /\epsilon_0$.
Alternatively, one could use eq. \eqref{6}. With $V_h=0$ and the charge distribution \eqref{9}, the potential is given by $$ V(\mathbf{r}) = -\frac{\rho_0}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int\limits_{B_R(0)} \! d^3 \mathbf{r}^\prime \, \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}^\prime|}. \tag{14} \label{14} $$ As to be expected, the integral \eqref{14} is invariant under rotations (i.e. $V(R \mathbf{r}) = V(r)$, for all $ R \in \rm SO(3)$) and one obtains $$V(r)= -\frac{\rho_0}{2 \epsilon_0} \int\limits_0^R \! dr^\prime r^{\prime^2} \int\limits_{-1}^1  \frac{du}{\sqrt{r^2+r^{\prime 2}-2 r r^\prime u}}, \tag{15}  $$ where $u$ is the cosine of the angle between the vectors $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r}^\prime$.
With all these hints, you should now be able to detect your numerous sign errors, misconceptions and calculational mistakes yourself.

Well done and thorough explanation! Thank you! It's about 2AM here so I'm only able to give it the once over for now and I'll need to look at this more tomorrow, but I can already see I messed up in equation (3). And yes, I did ignore the inhomogeneous part and forgot to mention it. I'll need to look over (5) as well as the translation invariance property to verify it myself. For (9) we're saying that $rho$ of the ball is the same in the infinite volume surrounding it, right? Also, what's $B_r(0)$ and $SO(3)$?

$B_r(0)$ denotes the ball with radius $r$ centered around the origin. $\rm SO(3)$ is the rotation group in three dimensions, i.e. the set of all real orthogonal $3 \times 3$ matrices with determinant one ($R^T R =R R^T = 1_3$, $\det R =1$. As the domain   and the integration measure in (14) are both SO(3) invariant, $V(R \mathbf{r}) =V(\mathbf{r})$ holds for $R \in \rm SO(3)$.

In (15) just looking at the bounds of integration and understanding from when I was looking at the Associated Legendre Equations before untangling how to solve Laplace's Equation in spherical coordinates, when we make the substitution $x = \cos(\theta)$, then our bounds shift from $0\le \theta \le \pi$ to $-1\le x\le 1$, so I assume you mean to say that u is the x substitution of the cosine of the azimuthal angle between $\textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{r}_0$. Also $\frac{1}{2\epsilon_0}$ indicates to me that we've already integrated out $\phi$ which simply is $2\pi$.

@ResearcherR 1. $\mathbf{r} \cdot \mathbf{r}^\prime = |\mathbf{r}| |\mathbf{r}^\prime| \cos \theta= r r^\prime u$. 2. The integration over $\phi$ was carried out yielding a factor $2 \pi$ (the integrand does not depend on $\phi$).

And yes $V_h$ should be obtained from the inhomogeneous BCs. The solution to an inhomogeneous problem with inhomogeneous BCs is the homogeneous solution satisfying inhomogeneous BCs + the inhomogeneous solution satisfying homogeneous BCs. $$V = V_p + V_h$$. In relation to Green's function and after applying Green's formula, I'm used to seeing it in the form $$V(\textbf{r}) = \int \rho(\textbf{r}_0)G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}0)d\textbf{r}0^3 + \oint{\partial S}\alpha \nabla{r'}G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0) \cdot d\textbf{S}$$ where $\alpha$ is the inhomogeneous BC(s) of the solution

Alright I'll get out of your way now! I'm going to try and work through this with your guidance now, and if I have any future questions, open up a separate question and try to make it less of a "solve this" and more of a conceptual type of question in the future as the moderators have warned me. Thank you for your help!

I finally sifted through the entirety of your answer and verified (13), and this isn't a conceptual question, but instead about what I think is a mistake in (15). Since our expanded integrand from (14) is $$-\frac{\rho_0 r'^2 \sin(\theta_0)}{2\epsilon \sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'\cos(\theta')}}$$, wouldn't we integrate over the $r'$s in the denominator as well? Should be $$V(r) = -\frac{\rho_0}{2\epsilon}\int_0^R\int_{-1}^1\frac{r'^2}{\sqrt{r^2+r'^2-2rr'u}}du dr'$$

@ResearcherR That is exactly what (15) means with the only difference that I used the common "physics" notation $\int\limits_0^R dr^\prime r^{\prime 2} \int\limits_{-1}^1 du  f(r^\prime,u)$ instead of the equivalent "mathematical" notation $\int\limits_0^R \int\limits_{-1}^1 r^{\prime 2} f(r^\prime,u) du , dr^\prime$.
